# Php count list of digits

Tags: php, count

I am getting o/p like "11111" and I want to sum all these digits that should become 5. But if I use count count it is showing one only i.e, 1.Rather it should show 5.

Below is my code,

```
$count = count($inventory['product_id']);

$product_total = $count;
echo $product_total;//o/p => 1.
```

I need echo $product_total;//o/p => 5.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following using [`str_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) to get an array with all characters (in your case digits) and using [`array_sum`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) to get the sum of all the digits:

```
$digits = "11112";
$arrDigits = str_split($digits);

echo array_sum($arrDigits); //6 (1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 2)
```

**Demo:** https://ideone.com/tZwi9J

Answer (score 0):

Count is used for counting array elements.

What you can do in PHP, is to iterate over a string using either a foreach (not 100% sure) or for loop for this and accessing the elements like array elements by their index:

```
$str = '111111123545';
$sum = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
    $sum += intval($str[$i]);
}

print $sum; // prints 26
```

---

Alternativly, you can split the string using no delimiter and using the [array_sum](http://php.net/array_sum)() function on it:

```
$str = '111111123545';
$sum = array_sum(str_split($str));
print $sum; // prints 26
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array_sum(str_split($number));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way to count the list of digits in PHP is:

```
// match only digits, returns counts
echo preg_match_all( "/[0-9]/", $str, $match ); 

// sum of digits
echo array_sum($match[0]);
```

Example:

```
$ php -r '$str="s12345abas"; echo "Count :".preg_match_all( "/[0-9]/", $str, $match ).PHP_EOL; echo "Sum :".array_sum($match[0]).PHP_EOL;'
Count :5
Sum :15
```